# Kunneth formular with coefficients the constructible sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ be complex algebraic varieties (possibly open and singular) and $A$ (resp. $B$) be a constructible sheaf of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces on $X$ (resp. $Y$). Do we have the Kunneth type isomorphisms:
$$H^k(X\times Y,A\boxtimes B)\simeq\bigoplus_{i+j=k}H^i(X,A)\otimes H^j(Y,B)?$$
Here $A\boxtimes B$ denotes $p_1^\ast A\otimes p_2^\ast B$.

P.S. If we consider the cohomology with compact supports, then we have
$$H^k_{\rm cpt}(X\times Y,A\boxtimes B)\simeq\bigoplus_{i+j=k}H^i_{\rm cpt}(X,A)\otimes H^j_{\rm cpt}(Y,B)$$
following from the projection formula for pushforward with compact supports.

Answer (score 4):

Theorem 4.3.14 in Dimca's *Sheaves and topology* says this is true. The compact version, Corollary 2.3.31, is indeed much easier as you suggest. Another reference Dimca gives is Schuermann's *Topology of Singular Spaces and Constructible Sheaves*, Corollary 2.0.4 but I cannot check that at the moment.